Am I a trader? (App store compliance: Manage European Union Digital Services Act trader requirements)
A query that I have as I have been working with app development and publishing activity for past few years now.
There is a new guidelines release made my Apple Store specifically for 27 territories of the EU where there is a need to mention the app publisher to be a trader or a non trader. Out of all the apps that I manage, there are some apps whose organizations are an FMCG but the app is solely used for the internal communication and action item review purpose. These internal apps are not made for any sell or purchase of products and are only focused on employee engagement and day to day activities. So my question is whether for such apps also, do I need to register the apple account as a trader?
for ref.
https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-compliance-information/manage-european-union-digital-services-act-trader-requirements/
We need to know that should we mark as trader or not as article is bit confusing?
